DB::Exception: Refreshable materialized views are experimental. Enable allow_experimental_refreshable_materialized_view to use
Want to create materialize view on clickhouse DB, Below are my sqlQuery :
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS tutorial.AL_DEMAND_views02
REFRESH EVERY 1 MINUTE
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
ORDER BY "Month"
POPULATE
AS
SELECT
    "Month",
    SUM("Values") AS "Values"
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM (select * from tutorial.AL_DEMAND))
GROUP BY
    "Month";

Error I got :
SQL Error [344] [07000]: Code: 344. DB::Exception: Refreshable materialized views are experimental. Enable allow_experimental_refreshable_materialized_view to use. (SUPPORT_IS_DISABLED) (version 23.12.3.40 (official build))
, server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://XX.XX.X.XX:8123/default, options={use_server_time_zone=false,use_time_zone=false}]@-543127256

From DBEaver I am able to create view, As I can run 2 queries at a time, below are the queries which are creating view.
SET allow_experimental_refreshable_materialized_view = 1;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS tutorial.AL_DEMAND_views02
REFRESH EVERY 1 MINUTE
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
ORDER BY "Month"
POPULATE
AS
SELECT
    "Month",
    SUM("Values") AS "Values"
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM (select * from tutorial.AL_DEMAND))
GROUP BY
    "Month";

From Java code, How do I create a materialize view

You can enable this setting using users profile, or using set command, but for set command you need to enable persistent session using session_id setting in connection string.
Anyway the easiest way is using default profile:
# cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/allow_experimental_refreshable_materialized_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<clickhouse>
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <allow_experimental_refreshable_materialized_view>1</allow_experimental_refreshable_materialized_view>
        </default>
    </profiles>
</clickhouse>

session_id: https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-java/issues/1017
